# PHP Curl image save an empty file

Tags: php, image, curl

i'm trying to get an gif image from a public website, but I get a white square as result, this is the code:

```
<?php
$image_url = 'http://www.meteoam.it/Storage/Catop/2021-02-05/CNMC_FAX_202102050000_ITALIA_SW@@@@@@_999100@@@@@@_012_000_@@@@.GIF';
$save_as = 'images/test.gif';

function get_web_page( $url, $binary = false )
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,     // Disabled SSL Cert checks
CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => $binary
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $content;
}

$raw = get_web_page( $image_url, true );
if(file_exists($save_as)){
unlink($save_as);
}
$fp = fopen($save_as,'x');
fwrite($fp, $raw);
?>
```

This is driving me crazy, fpopen is enabled from php.ini.

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of `$header`? Also, it appears you aren’t inspecting the status code, either.

Comment: The URL you shared doesn't return a gif file, and you should write what error do you get?

Comment: The code returns a blank page, no error or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting a protection when trying to curl images from this meteo/weather page. They will have checks that try to prevent accessing their files directly via curl (Referer Check, Cookie Check, User-Agent..).

**Just to clarify:** I *know* that they have checks. If you go to a content page on this site (e.g. http://www.meteoam.it/prodotti_grafici/nefoSfloc) you can see the images and you can also open them by their direct URL (You are then authorized to see those images). If you take the URL and open a fresh browser window (no existing cookies or session - e.g. in incognito mode) - you will get a clear message (in italian though) saying:

> Non disponi dei permessi necessari per accedere all'oggetto richiesto,
> oppure l'oggetto non può essere letto dal server.
>
> Buona navigazione!
> #Metweb Staff#

Comment: Thank you, do you know any way to perform the curl?